# I need to data preprocessing to do following:

Tags: r

I need to change following input data:

```
1 161 2
1 1897 2
17689 2
1547 1
1 32 1
2 453 1
2 73 1
3 86 1
3 9768 1
```

into:
161,1897,7689,547,32
453,73
86,9768

using R language ignoring the last column of input data

Answer (score 0):

We may use `split` - `split` the column 2 by the values of column 1 into a `list` of `vector`s

```
split(df1[[2]], df1[[1]])
```